# The meaning of the verb "to rake [one's gaze]"

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

I have a question about the verb "rake" in this sentence:

> He raked his gaze over me.

What does it mean particularly in this sentence? And what does "over me" indicate here? Shouldn't it be "...his gaze at me"?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: **rake** is often used with fingernails scratching the face, and so this figurative use might be intentionally summoning up those connotations. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raked+his+face%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=570966760&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1366&bih=692&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKlKT1bo33m7JHX9xKIseDJy6zhbNQ%3A1696510494411&ei=HrIeZYPUGJmt5NoPnuK-0AM&ved=0ahUKEwiD24GL-t6BAxWZFlkFHR6xDzoQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22raked+his+face%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhAicmFrZWQgaGlzIGZhY2UiMgUQIRirAkinJ1AAWLQjcAB4AJABAJgBUaAB6gKqAQE1uAEDyAEA-AEBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: "over" there means "from head to toe, across the length of my body".

Comment: Do you know if it is the correct use of "rake"?

Comment: It is a metaphorical use of **rake**.  An actual rake has pointy "fingers", and so to scratch someone's face with fingernails is not that different from using the garden tool. However, when looking a person's body over from head to toe ("ogling" them) is the action involved, there isn't such a clear and direct analogy. The gaze is the tool with sharp fingers.

Comment: I wonder why author used such a figurative word instead of "run his gaze over me/her". That implies for me that the gaze would be sharp and unpleasant, but when I was reading this sentence in the book, I didn't get that feeling out of it. It felt simply like the action was just performed.

Comment: I don't know the book, or anything about the speaker of those words, but they suggest the speaker found the gaze to be worse than unpleasant. Could you cite the source, if it is a book?

Comment: Of course, it is the book "Our twisted bonds" by Lexi Ryan. The other longer quote says: "Who says I don't need a bath too." Finn's gaze rakes over me and leaves happy little shivers in its path.

Comment: The title's *Twisted Bonds* suggests perhaps some subconscious sado-masochistic tendencies?

Answer (score 1):

It means that he thoroughly examined the breadth and length of me. The imagery has several components. First, a rake, as an implement, has many fingers that are spread wide. Second, in using a rake one often makes long strokes.  Third, a rake’s sharp teeth disturb at least the top layers of the surface to which it is being applied. Together, these three components make the author’s image a rather unpleasant one of being eyed in an at least somewhat distressing manner.

And as for *over* vice *at*, the former makes much more sense considering rakes’ purpose, how raking is performed, and what raking accomplishes.

Comment: It seems to be a variation of more common idioms like "to run your gaze/eyes over someone/something". ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-eye-over)). It is intensified by the use of "rake" rather than "run" or "cast".